# Is there a way to get audio from spotify

Tags: node.js, spotify

So I'm Working on a NodeJs project and am wondering if there is a way to get audio from Spotify Like you Input a song URL and It plays the track, I've looked all around and can only find stuff for the web browser, I don't know if they even have a way. If there is any info about this please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to make calls through the Spotify API.

You can read more about the API here: [Spotify API Documentation](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/quick-start/)

This is a node.js specific library that you may also want to check out:
[thelinmichael's node.js Spotify API Library](https://github.com/thelinmichael/spotify-web-api-node)

Comment: It is just wrong! There is no such api to send the audio track itself

Answer (score 1):

The answer provisioned and marked as correct is wrong.
The only way you can extract audio is by using a Windows VM, connect via RDP. Run a script to play Spotify programatically and record the audio.

Since this is the only solution. It is *not* possible to query data from Spotify.